# Using function to pass the user input via pointers not working

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm trying to get the input from the user input, and pass to the program main using pointer. It seems that the value isn't going through even tho I tried some alternatives.

For example, if i input 0.0001, when I return to the main function it outputs 0.0000

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputFloat(float *n);

int main() {
    float *number;
    printf("Insert number: ");
    inputFloat(number);
    printf("%1.4f", *number);
    return 0;
}

void inputFloat(float *n){
   float num;
   while (scanf("%f", &num) != 1 || num < 0) {
      scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
      printf("insert positive: ");
   }
   printf("%1.4f\n", num);
   n = &num;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tip or correction.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you forget that in C arguments are passed by value, and that includes pointers.

The argument variable `n` in the `inputFloat` function is local to the `inputFloat` function, all modifications (like assignments) to it will be lost once the function returns.

What I believe you are trying to to is emulating pass by reference, which indeed is done by using pointers. But then you pass a pointer to a normal variable using the address-of operator `&`:

```
float number;  // Not a pointer
inputFloat(&number);  // Pass a pointer to the variable number
```

To use this pointer, and to set the value of the original variable it points to, you need to dereference the pointer:

```
void inputFloat(float *n)
{
    // ...
    *n = num;  // Copy the value of num to the location where n is pointing
}
```